# How to get a member of a pointer to an instance of a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have a callback function called got_packet:

```
void got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet) {
  WMShark *shark = (WMShark *)args;

  WMPacket *foundPacket = [[WMPacket alloc] init];
  foundPacket.packetNumber = [[shark capturedPackets] count];

  foundPacket.timeStamp = header.ts; // <-- PROBLEM IS HERE

  ...

  NSLog(@"%@: %s", shark, packet);
}
```

I get a compile error `error: request for member 'ts' in something not a structure or union` on the line `foundPacket.timeStamp = header.ts;`.

---

The documentation says:

> ...
>   a const struct  pcap_pkthdr pointer to  a structure  with the  following mem-bers:
>
> - ts — a  struct timeval containing the time when the packet was captured
>
> ...

---

How can I access `ts`? Thanks.

---

For the die-hard C-developers, the square brackets are used in Objective-C, a superset of C. You can ignore this, they're initializers in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've the pointer to the struct, use the `->` operator instead of `.`:

```
header->ts
```

Comment: Thank God for you existing! =D

Comment: :-) As an alternative, (*header).ts should serve equally well.

Answer (score 2):

`header` is a pointer. You can access it like this `header->ts`

Answer (score 1):

As `header` is a pointer to a `pcap_pkthdr` instance, it needs to be dereferenced using `->` like so:

```
header->ts
```